# How can I put in my drawer echo with react-navigation lines in gray below the text?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to do something like this, the only thing I need to know is how to make the gray lines that appear under each component.
By the way I'm using react-navigation.
this is what I want to recreate, I just need to know how to make the intermediate gray line.
[Link the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PwWx.png)

My cod:

```
    const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Example: ScreenExample
},
{
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerWidth: width * 0.63,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: blue,
      inactiveTintColor: "rgb(105,105,104)",
      itemsContainerStyle: {
        textAlign: "center"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontFamily: "RobotoCondensed-Regular",
        fontWeight: "400",
        fontSize: 17,
        marginLeft: -5
      }
    },
    iconContainerStyle: {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
  <SafeAreaView
    style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: white }}
    forceInset={{ top: "never" }}
  >
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: "rgb(63,103,149)" }} />
    <View
      style={{
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(63,103,149)",
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowOffset: {
          height: 5
        }
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={require("./src/assets/Icon-Transparente.png")}
        style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScrollView>
</View>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create one common component like this,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
export default class UnderlinedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'grey' }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and use it like this,

```
<UnderlinedComponent> 
   <Text></Text>
</UnderlinedComponent >
<UnderlinedComponent> 
   <Button></Button>
</UnderlinedComponent >
```

this will just create a bottom border, you can customize it as per your need.

and if you don't know how to use `contentComponent` in a drawer. just [see this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4355)

Comment: thanks for answering, but I have a problem.
This is my code, and I do not know how to recreate what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for by researching at: https: //reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#contentoptions-for-draweritems
I found that inside the drawer there is a property called **itemStyle** and use it as follows 
itemStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        borderBottomColor: gray
      }
with this adding it to **contentOptions** I could create the lines below the items :)